# Truncate Integers Like C in SMT-LIB 2

Tags: z3, smt, cvc4

I'm passing the symbolic output of a symbolic execution engine to Z3 in SMT-LIB 2 format. I need it to truncate integers like they would be in C. So that `(assert (= 1 (/ 3 2)))` would be `SAT`.

These formulas might also have floats, so not all divisions should truncate. Just division of ints.

How does one do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Integer division is simply called `div`:

```
(assert (= 1 (div 3 2)))
(check-sat)
```

This produces:

```
sat
```